# Modifying Classpath UNIX (tcsh)

Tags: unix, classpath

I was trying to append a jar file to the classpath. I use the tcsh shell, and I used "set CLASSPATH = ($CLASSPATH /java/classes /home/tchin/myclasses)" which I got from the website:

http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/classpath.shtml

Now, my classpath has the jar file appended to it. Unfortunately, I made a typo while I was typing the location of the jar file. Also, there is no : preceding the location of my jar file (it just has space). Is there any way to undo this change or delete the jar location I just added and revert the classpath value to what it was before?

Also, could somebody please tell me how I could just append a jar file to the existing classpath when I use a tcsh shell?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the problem here is that your CLASSPATH already contains wrong paths. You can remove it only by resetting CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in tcsh, but I think you can reset CLASSPATH variable. The easiest way, I guess, would we to restart the computer and do what you do the second time. As an alternative you can try to print out the CLASSPATH variable and set it to the fixed value. To print it out do:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

And the just set it out without referencing to previous values:

```
set CLASSPATH = (/previous/path1 /prev/path2 /your/new/path)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I logged off and logged back in. The classpath has been restored to its actual value! How could I append the jar file to the classpath? When I use set CLASSPATH = ($SCLASSPATH:/home/downloads/filename.jar), I get the bad modifier error for the : Thank you very much again!